# What does the Wanted Items ticker on the Affinity Chart mean?

Tags: xenoblade-chronicles-3

At the bottom of the Affinity Chart there's a scrolling text box with various items labeled from 1 to 10. Clicking the left stick toggles the text on and off, as indicated by the prompt "Ⓛ Show Wanted Items".

What's the purpose of the wanted items ticker? Who wants these items?

[image: wanted items ticker]

Comment: It's probably referring to the Collectopaedia cards

Comment: @Wondercricket Would they be for a specific person's collectopedia or just any open collectopedia's in general?

Comment: That's a good question, I'm not entirely sure at this moment in time

Comment: I did some visual comparisons and it is indeed related to the items requested in the Collectopedia. It appears to be for all requests in general, not really any specific requests. Furthermore what drives what items appear in this list is very unclear; best explanation I could come up with it shows items with the highest cumulative count through non-completed requests?